# `read.table` error with a tab separated file

Tags: r

I have a text document that is separated by tab. I did notice a bunch of tabs after the data in the text doc and am unsure if that is the issue here.

I have set the working directory:

> setwd("D:/Classes/CSC/gmcar_price")

Then I attempt to read the table using

> data=read.table("gmcar_price.txt", header=T)

But this error is coming up:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>             line 11 did not have 13 elements

Any idea what is going on here? I have looked at line 11 and all the data is there.

Edit:

this is the format of the data

Price,Mileage,Make,Model,Trim,Type,Cylinder,Liter,Doors,Cruise,Sound,Leather

Comment: Would help if you show how your data looks like.

Comment: Do you expect each line to have 13 columns? Perhaps one of the previous lines is missing some data (as sashkello says, it's probably something specific to your text file)

Comment: If the separators are tabs, throw in `sep = "\t"` as an argument to `read.table`. Extra tabs in your file could well be the problem... maybe you can find/replace them out before loading?

Comment: So could the issue be all the extra tabs at the end that causes R to see a bunch of random X1, X2, X3.... and it just inserts N/A

Comment: I did try that shujaa but I was unable to do it for tab. I was thinking about loading the data into excel and saving a csv file and attempt to upload it again.

Comment: Try to open it in notepad or something that will reveal blank cells that you cannot see in Excel.  This behavior can be caused by extra commas or tabs at the end of a line. Delete any you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 data=read.table("gmcar.price.txt", header=T, sep = "\t")
```

Thanks to shujaa, this solved the issue that I was having.